# How to find integral of the equation $y'=\frac{2y-2x}{x+y-2}$ Check if solution is right

Tags: integration

I have equation $y'=\frac{2y-2x}{x+y-2}$ and the task is to find general integral. I tried to solve it, but not sure if I'm right and if answer is correct.

1. System of the equations:

- $2y-2x=0$
- $x+y-2=2$
- Answer: $x_{0}=y_{0}=1$

2. Changes

- $u=x-x_{0}$ and $v=y-y_{0}​$
- $x=u+x_{0} \: \:\: y=v+y_{0}$

3. Put it to equation:

- $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dv}{du}=v'$
- $v'=\frac{2(v+y_{0})-2(u+x_{0})}{u+x_{0}+v+y_{0}-2}=\frac{2v+2y_{0}-2u-2x_{0}}{u+x_{0}+v+y_{0}-2}=\frac{2v-2u}{u+v}$

4. Changes: $w=\frac{v}{u} \: \: \: v=wu \: \: \: v'=w+uw'$

- $w+uw'=\frac{wu-2u}{u+wu}$
- ($v'=\frac{2wu-2u}{u+wu}$)

5. Calculate using equations from 4

- $uw'=\frac{2wu-2u}{u+wu}-w$
- $uw'=\frac{-w^2+w-2}{1+w}$

6. Separation method

- $u\frac{dw}{du}=\frac{-w^2+w-2}{1+w}$
- $\frac{1+w}{-w^2+w-2}dw=\frac{1}{u}du$

7. Find integrals

- $\int_{}^{}\frac{1+w}{-w^2+w-2}dw=-\frac{w^2}{-2w^2+2w-4}+c$
- $\int_{}^{}\frac{1}{u}du=ln(|u|)+c$

Answer (score 4):

$$y'=\frac{2y-2x}{x+y-2}~~~~(1)$$
Let $X=x-1, Y=y-1$, then (1) becomes
$$\frac{dY}{dX}=\frac{2(Y-X)}{X+Y}~~~~(2)$$
This is homogeneous equation, take $Y=VX$, then
$$X\frac{dV}{dX}+V=\frac{2(V-1)}{V+1} \implies -\int \frac{V+1}{V^2-V+2}dV=\int \frac{dX}{X} +C.$$
Now you can proceed from here.

Comment: OH! yes, thanks, corrected now.

Comment: @Z Ahmed Thanks, but is my way of solving correct or not, because I get (2) in my 3rd step

Comment: The mistake is in your 5th step where $x^2$ appears. There should be only $u$ and $w$. Like in my case $X$ and $V$.

Comment: @Z Ahmed It's my mistake, it should be w, edited my soulution